# Dynamically building Func<Tn,T> with a dynamic body using Expression

Tags: c#, dynamic, delegates, expression, func

NOTE: `Func<Tn,T>` = could be any number of types

I recently picked back up a project i had been working on for a while and was auditing the code. Before i had taken a break I was aggravated by the implementation of a method so I spent about 2 days trying to work on it to make it better. I am trying to dynamically create a `Func<>` with the generic type parameters count, type and return type known at runtime .

the current block of code i use right now is this switch statement: (sorry for the format)

```
foreach (var member in LinkedDocument.GetType()
                           .GetMethods()
                           .Where(
                               method =>
                                   method.GetCustomAttributes(
                                       typeof(ScriptingMethodAttribute), true)
                                         .Length != 0))
{
Delegate method;

switch (member.GetParameters()
           .Count())
{
    case 0:
        method = new Func<dynamic>(() => member.Invoke(LinkedDocument, null));
        break;
    case 1:
        method = new Func<object, dynamic>(
            param => member.Invoke(
                LinkedDocument, new[]
                {
                    param
                }));
        break;
    case 2:
        method =
            new Func<object, object, dynamic>(
                (param1, param2) => member.Invoke(
                    LinkedDocument, new[]
                    {
                        param1,
                        param2
                    }));
        break;
    case 3:
        method =
            new Func<object, object, object, dynamic>(
                (param1, param2, param3) => member.Invoke(
                    LinkedDocument, new[]
                    {
                        param1,
                        param2,
                        param3
                    }));
        break;
    case 4:
        method =
            new Func<object, object, object, object, dynamic>(
                (param1, param2, param3, param4) => member.Invoke(
                    LinkedDocument, new[]
                    {
                        param1,
                        param2,
                        param3,
                        param4
                    }));
        break;
    default:
        throw new NotImplementedException();
}

initalScope.Add(member.Name.ToLower(), method);
```

}
I am attempting to use Expression Tree's to dynamically build it and am reading tutorials, but I am just not getting it. all of the examples that I see use statically typed types exp: `Func<object, object, dynamic>`.

I do not want to do this. I want to dynamically build it depending upon the methods parameter count. this is what i have so far..

```
var assem = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(Func<object>));
var type = assem.GetType(string.Format("Func`{0}", obj.GetParameters().Count()));
var typeArr = obj.GetParameters().Select(param => param.ParameterType).ToList();
typeArr.Add(obj.ReturnType);

var ctrInfo = type.GetConstructor(typeArr.ToArray());
var expType = Expression.New(type);
```

and I assume that this is where `Expression` would come into play. but I'm just really having a hard time deciphering the tutorials and how to integrate a solution into my problem.

NOTE: I do not want the issue solved for my specific problem, Just some guidence would be nice.

Thanks for the help.

**Update**:

---

while rethinking my implementation, I remember why i don't want to use `object[]`.

I would still have to use something like this:

```
switch (member.GetParameters().Count())
{
    case 0:
        method = new Func<dynamic>(() => member.Invoke(LinkedDocument, null));
        break;
    case 1:
        method = new Func<object, dynamic>(param => member.Invoke(LinkedDocument, new[] { param }));
        break;
    default:
        method = new Func<object[], dynamic>(
            param => member.Invoke(
                LinkedDocument, param));
        break;
}
```

or:

```
var paramCount = member.GetParameters().Count();
if(paramCount == 0)
    method = new Func<dynamic>(() => member.Invoke(LinkedDocument, null));
else if(paramCount == 1)
    method = new Func<object, dynamic>(param => member.Invoke(LinkedDocument, new[] { param }));
else
    method = new Func<object[], dynamic>(
           param => member.Invoke(
               LinkedDocument, param));
```

which works... but... i just think it could be done more dynamically to encompass all the methods.

Comment: Do i read it correctly from your code, that all your different delegates are actually just a call to the eversame `obj.Invoke` method?

Comment: yes. they are all class methods that i am grabbing via reflection. ill put the preceding loop in the question.

Comment: Ahh, i see your edit. Now it makes more sense...

Comment: im sorry i mis-read your response. I am calling multiple methods, with a different amount of parameters. see update. I updated with the loop that `obj` is in.

Comment: When you have stored the different delegates in *initalScope*, how do you make sure that always the correct number of arguments for each particular delegate are passed to the delegate?

Comment: To me it still looks like you could more easily store and invoke the *MethodInfo* objects in *initalScope*, or - if you do not want to expose the *MethodInfo* objects - just use and store delegates of a single type `Func<object[], dynamic>` (which would essentially wrap *MethodInfo.Invoke*)

Comment: I am setting these methods in a scope of a scripting engine for IronPython. I forget why i cant use `object[]` but i remember testing and it not working out for method overloads.

Comment: maybe i need to rethink my implementation...

Comment: @elgonzo, I updated with an explanation.

Comment: Perhaps mention in your question that it is about IronPython and how these delegates should be used in this context - and also add an IronPython tag to your question, perhaps. However i am sorry that i can't be of much help regarding IronPython, since i don't know it and thus am not aware of any kind of conventions/restrictions it imposes on such delegates...

Comment: No, thank you for your help. I really appreciate it. Sorry i didn't mention it earlier. The basis of my question was more geared toward `Expression` , However probably not the most efficient way. I really just wanted to learn something new.

Answer (score 0):

1. Get a list of ParameterExpressions.   I did this by calling GetParameters and then using Select and ToList to convert from ParameterInfo to ParameterExpression
2. Create an expression to call your method with your parameters
3. Determine your delegate type.  It looked like you had a working method for this but I also included my code below.
4. Create a lambda expression passing in your delegate type, expression to call the method (this is the body of the lambda expression) and your parameters.
5. Set "method" equal to the compiled version of your lambda expression.
6. Do whatever you want with the delegate.

Code:

```
foreach (var member in LinkedDocument.GetType()
                       .GetMethods()
                       .Where(
                           method =>
                               method.GetCustomAttributes(
                                   typeof(ScriptingMethodAttribute), true)
                                     .Length != 0))
{
    var parameters = member.GetParameters().Select(v => Expression.Parameter(v.ParameterType, v.Name)).ToList();
    var caller = Expression.Call(member, parameters);
    var delegateType = GetFuncType(member.GetParameters().Select(v => v.ParameterType).ToArray(), member.ReturnType);
    var methodLambda = Expression.Lambda(delegateType, caller, parameters);

    Delegate method = methodLambda.Compile();

    initalScope.Add(member.Name.ToLower(), method);
}
```

Here is the code I used to get the delegate/func type

```
public static Type[] _baseFuncTypes = new Type[] { typeof(Func<>), typeof(Func<,>), typeof(Func<,,>), typeof(Func<,,,>), typeof(Func<,,,,>), typeof(Func<,,,,,>), typeof(Func<,,,,,,>), typeof(Func<,,,,,,,>), typeof(Func<,,,,,,,,>) };

private static Type GetFuncType(Type[] parameterTypes, Type returnType)
{
    Array.Resize(ref parameterTypes, parameterTypes.Length + 1);
    parameterTypes[parameterTypes.Length - 1] = returnType;

    return _baseFuncTypes[parameterTypes.Length - 1].MakeGenericType(parameterTypes);
}
```